# Table Class disappears from DBcontext object of EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, data-access-layer

I have updated my edmx file for the changes done in database.

The Database diagram shows the newly added table(RelyingParty).
Using DBContext object i am trying to perform operation in it at my DAL layer, But the table class keeps disappearing/missing from the code.

Initially it was present and after some time it says - '**RelyingPart is not part of the model for the currentcontext**'

[image: ERROR]

*What i tried?*

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
      modelBuilder.Entity<RelyingParty>().ToTable("RelyingParty");
 }
```

In Entites.Context.cs class. Still i am facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to you edmx file is not updated correctly [How to: Update an .edmx File when the Database Changes (Entity Data Model Tools)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716697(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for Response.I have updated edmx the same way. I have been doing the same procedure to update edmx file for months.

Comment: Else you may need to delete edmx and add it ones more .@kaarthickraman